# Question with equalities of norms with a multiple

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces

Say I have a norm. We know that for the elements u,v of this norm we have $\|u\| = -t\|v\|$

Does this imply $u = \pm tv?$
Or does it imply $u = - tv?$

And why does it imply this equality?

Thank you

Comment: Norm is distance from the origin, and can't be negative. Any unit vector has the same norm, so such an equation does not follow.

Comment: Does this follow for t being a real constant? $\|u + tv\| = 0$ implies $ u = -tv$

Comment: That's another question, and yes, since only the zero vector has zero norm, $\|u+tv\|=0$ does imply $u+tv=0$, which is equivalent to $u=-tv$.

Comment: Thank you for answering it, when we talk about elements of the norm, do we always talk about vectors? Can we talk about say matricies if the norm was defined on matricies and would the same equality hold?

Comment: Yes, matrices indeed form a normed space, therefore they could also be seen as 'vectors' (elements of a normed space).

Comment: Thank you much much :)